# Make arrows inside lstlisting

Tags: listings, arrows, sourcecode

Inside my `lstlisting` environment I want to make the assignment symbol an arrow instead  of `=`. How can I do that? Adding just `\leftarrow` doesn't work, because then the whole word is displayed.

Comment: You might try `mathescape=true, literate={=}{$\leftarrow$}{1}` in your `listings` definition. `:)`

Comment: Furthermore, assuming that your language uses `==` for the equality relation (as opp. assignment), you could use `literate={=}{$\leftarrow$}{1},{==}{$=$}{1}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested by Jubobs, here is a simple document elaborating on the comments, showing how to use math literals to use `\leftarrow` for assignment in a `lstlistings` environment.

**Preamble**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}  

\lstset{columns=fullflexible,
        mathescape=true,
        literate=
               {=}{$\leftarrow{}$}{1}
               {==}{$={}$}{1},
        morekeywords={if,then,else,return}
        }
```

Here, we use `\lstset` to change the settings for all `lstlisting` environments in the document. You could put these options in the argument to an individual argument if you prefer. I've set the columns to `fullflexible` for the sake of presentation, and added keywords because I haven't chosen any language. The setting `mathescape=true` will allow us to use math-mode to typeset special character combinations.

The list of 'literates' (note: no commas separating the items in the list!) tells `listings` how to typeset special character combinations. Here, assignment (`=`) is being typeset with `\leftarrow`, and equality testing (`==`) is being typeset with the equality symbol. The `{}` after the symbols is necessary for correct spacing in the `fullflexible` column option: it has no effect with `fixed`. Note the comma after the last literal, before the `morekeywords` option.

**Sample document**

```
\begin{document}  
\begin{lstlisting}
  a = 1;
  if (a == 0)
    then do not panic, Citizen, everything is under control!
    else rest easy, Citizen, everything is fine!
  return to your daily business!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Typeset output]